# {"error":{"code":"ER_PARSE_ERROR","errno":1064,"sqlMessage":"You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: javascript, mysql

```js
const sql = 'SELECT * FROM ufonight.casos'
connect.query(sql,(error,results) =>{
    this.return_error(res,error,results)
})
```

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
    "errno": 1064,
    "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[object Object]' at line 1",
    "sqlState": "42000",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM ufonight.casos WHERE id=[object Object]"
  }
}
```

what is wrong?

Comment: According to the error, "You have an error in your SQL syntax". The example given at the top does not output that error. Please provide a [mcve] which shows this error.

Comment: Please check the code you've provided, it doesn't seem to match the error you are getting. In your error the faulty query is `"sql": "SELECT * FROM ufonight.casos WHERE id=[object Object]"`, but that doesn't match the code you've provided above `const sql = 'SELECT * FROM ufonight.casos'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JSON response you're getting in return, your SQL query is a little bit different from what's shown in your `sql` variable.

My guess, based on the response, is that you tried concatenating a string with an object variable and you didn't call the key where your id was stored. Try logging that `[object Object]` and concatenating its correct key instead of the entire object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i forgot a req in the controller like:

```
module.exports = app => {
app.get('/casos', (req, res) => {
    
    Casos.search(res,req)
})
```

the correct was :

```
module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/casos', (req, res) => {
        
        Casos.search(res)
    })
```

...
thank you <3